# Referencing values as coordinates in other worksheets

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel to create a solar calculator. I have 3 values in a Report worksheet; a Zone No (either 7E, 10 or 11), Roof Pitch, and Orientation. The Zone reference will be a Zone worksheet, and the Roof Pitch and Orientation will be coordinate values in the Zone worksheets. I need to be able to populate a cell with the value at the coordinates (roof pitch and orientation).

Comment: Thats exactly right, I need to find the value of the column and row reference of the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Something of this kind might suit, where the inputs are in G1:I1 :

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A"&H1+1),INDIRECT(G1&"!A1:E3"),I1+1,0)
```